# About Primary Decomposition - $\displaystyle\cup^n_{i=1}\mathfrak{p}_i=\{x\in A:(\mathfrak{a}:x)\neq\mathfrak{a}\}$

Tags: commutative-algebra, ideals, primary-decomposition

I am studying, on Commutative Algebra, this proposition, from Atiyah and MacDonald (page 53)

[image: Prop.4.7]

I understood the proof, but I am unsure to transpose the proof from zero ideal to the general case $\displaystyle\cup^n_{i=1}\mathfrak{p}_i=\{x\in A:(\mathfrak{a}:x)\neq\mathfrak{a}\}$.

Thanks in advance for some light!

Answer (score 1):

What you need to show is that everything involved in the theorem respects taking the inverse image under the map $\pi : A \to A/\mathfrak{a}$.

If you have trouble showing something respects this map, let me know and I'm happy to give more details!

Comment: Thank you so much, I'll try and return as soon as possible!

Comment: Hi. I am trying today, do you think is it necessary (and maybe sufficient) to prove that $\cup\sqrt{(I:a)}=\{a\in A:(I:a)\neq I\}$? Many thanks!